# How to represent white spaces as dots without modifying the text nodes within a contenteditable div

Tags: html, css

Is it possible with CSS to represent white spaces as dots instead? These DOM nodes should be immutable, hence modifying them via javascript wouldn't be an option.

For instance

```
<div contenteditable="true">some dummy text   </div>
```

would become

```
"some.dummy.text..."
```

Comment: Couldn't find a way to fill it with just css, but if you need dots between two span tags, here's an example. http://codepen.io/Kseso/pen/fxrsL

Comment: What's your aim?  Default white-space handling (`white-space: normal`) will collapse multiple spaces into one, so you'd only see one white-space dot even if your HTML source content contains a long sequence of them...

Comment: can you use javascript instead?

Comment: @Roysh javascript would be fine

Comment: @searlea my aim is to present to the user how many white spaces are being inserted, since they play an important role for this type of input. btw, I'm using contenteditable.

Comment: @Frutis Interesting example, but does not achieve what I'm aiming. I'm specifically trying to "replace" the white spaces within a content editable div.

Comment: My best bet would be to simply use a modified font-face that has a dot (or whatever) as the whitespace character... This way, copy-pasting or the likes will work no problems, it will only be visual.

Comment: @Salketer Very interesting approach, I guess I will give it a try.

Comment: @pelican_george Hello George, I'd be interested in the approach you have used. Please answer your own question if you found the solution.

Comment: @Salketer I've tried to use a custom font and replaced some of the whitespaces with my own custom glyphs (e.g. a dot). It worked on most browsers, but google chrome for some reason does some weird mapping with whitespaces. As an example: if I changed the glyph for the regular whitespace (U0020), chrome would map zero width and other whitespaces to (U0020), which ended up by popping up dots everywhere. I'm still waiting to find a solution for this. Any ideas?

Comment: @pelican_george are you sure chrome is not just "falling back" on the whitespace character if there are no valid mapping for the other empty characters? Does your font have other characters?

Comment: @Salketer I guess so, I used CenturyGothic as a test and edited U0020 glyph with FontForge. Have you tried this approach before?

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can think of is with jQuery:

```
$('div').html($('div').text().replace(/ /g,"."));
```

Here's a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/atg5m6ym/5876/

Comment: Unfortunately, I would be replacing the white spaces with another  character and mutating the text nodes. The idea is to only change the visual representation and not affect a possible copy/paste or data manipulation.

Comment: You can always modify the character

Comment: What if the text is "some dummy text with a final period."

Comment: sure, it works one way. But the reverse operation will miss the last period (just as an example). I need for the original contents to be untouched, also it's an content editable div with high input from the user. The less goin on the client side, the better.

Comment: Well if the period appears only at the end, you can do the same only for a sub string that doesn't include the last char

Comment: For that specific example it would work. But the contents of the div is dynamic/inserted by users. Quite often you'll see sentences and periods. Even if I change the character to another type of period (e.g bullet point), I would have the same risks.

Comment: So how about, instead of changing white space to a `.` replace to a `\.`